# How to create a facebook app and connect it to my old facebook page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a webpage and a facebook-page with a decent number of followers (fans). Now I want to integrate facebook in my webpage using the JS-SDK, this requires an application_ID from facebook. Creating an app from scratch will give me one, but it will not be connected to my old facebook page.

Is it possible to use my old facebook-page as a fan-page for a facebook app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing it seems like there is no way of connecting an old facebook page with a new facebook application. I ended up creating a seperate fb-application and keeping my old page. I use the new application to allow people to post their content on facebook, but I use the old page for likes to my website. Hopes this helps others wondering.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about the same thing. I am creating a CakePHP application and I use Facebook in this application as well. I've had a Facebook page for my website for awhile and right now I have over 1000 followers/likes.

I wanted to get an API Key and Secret Key for that page, or create an APP from the page. I've looked everywhere on FB and cant find anything related. I really need to do that and if FB wont allow it, I really wanted to understand why.

If you found anything related to this please let me know. Thanks.